# Select element with one attribute OR another attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to select all elements that have one of a list of attributes.
For example, I want to select all elements that have either a `mandatory` attribute, or `validate='true'` or both.

I tried this:

```
$('[mandatory="true",validate]').each(...
```

But I get an error.

I can't find any alternatives online. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: why not using [data-mandatory="true",data-validate="true"] ?

Comment: Because that will select elements have have both, I want elements that have either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To select *"all elements that have either a mandatory attribute, or validate='true' or both"*, use

```
$('[mandatory],[validate="true"]')
```

If what you really want is to have at least one of those attributes with value "true", use

```
$('[mandatory="true"],[validate="true"]')
```

Regarding your comment : if you wanted to select elements having *both* attributes, you'd simply remove the comma.

Comment: That will only select elements that have both attributes, won't it? See http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: @bukko This "Multiple Selector" works as per http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/, as distinct from the "Multiple _Attribute_ Selector" at http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: @bukko No, that would select all elements having the attribute `mandatory` or having the attribute `validate` with value true.